# JavaScript simplify conditional expression to something more readable

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
if (!(a === false && b === true)) {
  // do something
}
```

Here's a truth table for my expression:

```
a      b      !(a === false && b === true)
false  false  true
false  true   false
true   false  true
true   true   true
```

The expression `!(a === false && b === true)` is a bit of a mouthful, how would I simplify this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take

```
a || !b
```

instead.

```js
const
    fn = (a, b) => a || !b;

console.log(fn(false, false)); //  true
console.log(fn(false, true));  // false
console.log(fn(true, false));  //  true
console.log(fn(true, true));   //  true
```

The result takes only boolean values and  [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(a && b) = !a || !b 
!(a || b) = !a && !b
```